# Ошибка "Error in POL_Wine"

Tags: ubuntu, photoshop, wine

Пытаюсь установить Photoshop в Ubuntu, используя Wine. В процессе получаю ошибку
`Error in POL_Wine` с текстом "Похоже, Wine прервал работу". Как это исправить и в чём заключается ошибка?

Comment: установите через Play on Linux

Comment: я через него и устанавливаю

Comment: POL это и есть Play On Linux. @CreatorGod попробуйте воспользоваться подобным гайдом, я примерно подобным образом успешно устанавливал. https://losst.ru/ustanovka-photoshop-cs6-v-linux

Comment: Play on Linux - багованая приблуда. Её задача лишь в том, чтобы всё делалось одним кликом через гуи, но в линуксах так не бывает. Ставьте через обычный Wine (+ Winetricks, если нужны какие-то библиотеки) и если там есть ошибка, то вам хотя бы выдаст причину. Wine естественно должен быть последней версии, а не десятилетней давности, как принято в Play on Linux.

Comment: А вообще, если честно, я не понимаю нафига люди ставят себе линукс не желая пользоваться его родным софтом (вроде того же гимпа). Для фотошопа есть венда, к чему все эти извращения?